# Type Error: Sum doesn't allow distinct (Django)

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem in django, It tells me that "Sum doesn't allow distinct". 
It is working fine in my friends' computers but it is not working in my computer. 
Could you please help me? 
I will share screenshot also with the question. 
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlJhf.png)

Comment: Can you copy the code of the relevant view in the question. Please do not post *images* of code, but the code itself. idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode (did not dv, this only lists why posting images is *not* a good idea).

Comment: Can you also share the version of python and Django?

Comment: The `distinct=` feature was added in Django-3.0. So likely you are using a different version of Django.

Comment: @SayedAhmad. yeah sure. 
Python 3.5
Django 2.2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Django version is lover than 3 please upgrade it to latest version.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`distinct=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Sum.distinct) was added in [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0). Older versions of Django have *no* `distinct` parameter, hence the error. Indeed, if we look at the documentation of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), we see no `distinct` parameter for the [**`Sum(..)`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Sum).

You should upgrade the Django version in your virtual environment. For example with:

```
pip3 install Django --upgrade
```

If you are working together with a friend on a project, it might be better to include the requirements in the repository together with the version number. You can obtain such a list with:

```
pip3 freeze
```

If you write this to a file (for example with I/O redirection), then you can install the packages at another envrionment with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```